# How to center font awesome icons to a background-image

Tags: html, css, margin, padding, font-awesome

I'm trying to align font awesome icons in the middle of the of the background image when I add `position:relative;` and use `top:xxpx;` it works but I want to figure out a way where I don't have to use position. Attached is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mbfoxh5L/) of my code, and a snippet below.

Both vertically and horizontally centered.

```css
.footer-top {
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url("https://s4.postimg.org/714d8ul8d/footer-black.png");
}

.footer-top a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.navbar-list {
  padding-left: 540px;
  display: inline;
}

.navbar-list:hover {
  color: #fe5b1f;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar-icons {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="footer-top">
  <ul class="navbar-list" id="icons-list">
    <li class="navbar-icons">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-6" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar-icons">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-6" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar-icons">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-square fa-6" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use `position`?

Comment: @MichaelCoker When I use position, other elements on the page also end up moving, so i wanted to find a solution that does not disturb any other parts of the page.

Comment: If my answer works, then using `position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` on `.navbar-list` would also work and not shift around anything on the page.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Also, when I am using position relative or absolute, everything looks good on my computer BUT when I am trying to open the same website on different computer, things are going back and forth where I have applied position relative or absolute. That is the main reason why I don't want to you position relative or position absolute. `Can u suggest some best way to use position relative or position absolute ?` In every section of website, I am getting rid of position relative or position absolute.

Comment: When you use position absolute/relative, it depends on what you're doing as to why it might not scale properly on different screens. In general, the best practice is to use relative units (`%` or `em` or something) with the `top/left/right/bottom` properties, versus using fixed units like `px`. But it really depends on what you're doing.

Comment: The reason why I use position relative is to move the contents towards left, right, top, bottom on a webpage but when I try to open the same webpage on different computer, things go back and forth where I have applied position relative or absolute with top, left, bottom, right properties. That's why I don't prefer using position relative or position absolute. `Just wondering, what is the best way to use position: relative or position: absolute with the left, right, top and bottom properties ?`

Comment: My answer is the same - it depends on what you're doing. There is no single best way to use those properties. CSS is complicated. The best advice I can give is what I said - use relative units (%, em, etc) for positioning over fixed units (px). BUt sometimes fixed is better than relative - it really just depends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;` on the parent to put the child in the dead center. Then use `padding: 0` on the `ul` to remove the default left padding.

```css
.footer-top {
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url("https://s4.postimg.org/714d8ul8d/footer-black.png");
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.footer-top a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.navbar-list {
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-list:hover {
  color: #fe5b1f;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar-icons {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="footer-top">
  <ul class="navbar-list" id="icons-list">
    <li class="navbar-icons"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-6" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>

    <li class="navbar-icons"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-6" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li class="navbar-icons"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-square fa-6" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You say you don't want to use `position`, but because it causes other elements to shift around on the page. If you use `position: absolute` on the `ul`, nothing else will move around because of that.

```css
.footer-top {
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url("https://s4.postimg.org/714d8ul8d/footer-black.png");
  position: relative;
}

.footer-top a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.navbar-list {
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);  
}

.navbar-list:hover {
  color: #fe5b1f;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar-icons {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="footer-top">
  <ul class="navbar-list" id="icons-list">
    <li class="navbar-icons"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-6" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>

    <li class="navbar-icons"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-6" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li class="navbar-icons"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-square fa-6" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```